# Unable to share controller instance via require in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a confirm box which I want to attach another directive to called `confirmBoxToggle`, but I'm unable to share the same controller instance in order for it to work. I've looked at multiple examples and also read the docs to see if I'm doing something crazy, but the only thing I can see is that I don't declare my controller inside the directive but rather giving a reference to it. But I can't see this being the issue.

I get this error when doing this:

```
Controller 'confirmBox', required by directive 'confirmBoxToggle', can't be found!
```

What am I doing wrong?

The box directive:

```
core.directive('confirmBox', [function() {

    return {
        scope: {},
        controller: 'ConfirmBoxCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'confirmBox',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/components/core/confirmation-box.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        }
    };
}]);
```

The toggle directive:

```
core.directive('confirmBoxToggle', [function() {

    return {
        scope: {},
        require: '^confirmBox',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            element.on('click', function() {
                ctrl.toggleBox();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The controller for both directives:

```
core.controller('ConfirmBoxCtrl', [function() {

    var confirmBox = this;

    confirmBox.toggleBox = function() {
        confirmBox.isActive = !confirmBox.isActive;
    };
}]);
```

I use the directives like this:

```
<confirm-box></confirm-box>
<span confirm-box-toggle>Delete</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller *confirm* or *confirmBox* can't be found?
Do you use that controller elsewhere, and does it work on it's own?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you used `require: '^confirmBox'` that means while using `confirmBoxToggle` directive, it must be wrap with `confirmBox`directive(should be there in parent element as `^`) so that you could access to the `confirmBox` link function 4th parameter.

**HTML**

```
<confirm-box>
   <span confirm-box-toggle>Delete</span>
</confirm-box>
```

Also you can't have `templateUrl` inside your `confirmBox` directive, which will replace your `<span confirm-box-toggle>Delete</span>` html by the template loaded form `templateUrl`.

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LIJ9HpR8vAaIhDB3jZBV?p=preview)